# Custom function to mutate a new column for row means using starts_with()

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a data frame for which I want to create columns for row means. Each row mean column should be computed for a group of columns in the data. which are related to each other. I can differentiate between the groups of columns using dplyr's `starts_with()`. Since I have several groups of columns to calculate row means for, I'd like to build a function to do it. For some reason, I fail to get it to work.

### Data

```r
df <- data.frame("europe_paris" = 1:10, 
                 "europe_london" = 11:20, 
                 "europe_rome" = 21:30,
                 "asia_bangkok" = 31:40,
                 "asia_tokyo" = 41:50,
                 "asia_kathmandu" = 51:60)
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA),
                                                 prob = c(0.70, 0.30),
                                                 size = length(cc), 
                                                 replace = TRUE) ]))

df

   europe_paris europe_london europe_rome asia_bangkok asia_tokyo asia_kathmandu
1             1            NA          NA           NA         41             51
2            NA            12          22           NA         42             52
3             3            13          23           33         43             NA
4            NA            14          NA           NA         44             54
5            NA            15          25           35         45             55
6             6            NA          NA           36         46             56
7             7            17          27           NA         47             57
8            NA            18          28           38         48             NA
9             9            19          29           39         49             NA
10           10            NA          30           40         NA             60
```

I want to create a new column for the row means of each continent, across cities. One column for Asia cities, and one for Europe. Each run of the function will be fed by the name of a continent, to guide which columns to pick.

### My attempt to build the function

This attempt is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54705864/6105259).

```r
continent_mean <- 
  function(continent)  {
  df %>%
  select(starts_with(as.character(continent))) %>%
  mutate(., (!!as.name(continent)) == rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

However, running this code results in a weird behavior, as it seemingly returns the same dataset, with just the selected columns according to `starts_with()`, but it doesn't generate a new column for row means.

```r
continent_mean("asia")

   asia_bangkok asia_tokyo asia_kathmandu
1            31         41             51
2            32         42             52
3            33         43             53
4            34         44             54
5            35         45             55
6            36         46             56
7            37         47             57
8            38         48             58
9            39         49             59
10           40         50             60
```

What am I missing here? I thought this could be due to the `==` rather than `=` in `mutate()`, but a single `=` throws an error, so it seems not to be the solution either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `quo_name` to assign column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

continent_mean <- function(df, continent)  {
    df %>%
      select(starts_with(continent)) %>%
      mutate(!!quo_name(continent) := rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE))
}

continent_mean(df, "asia")


#   asia_bangkok asia_tokyo asia_kathmandu asia
#1            NA         41             51   46
#2            NA         42             52   47
#3            33         43             NA   38
#4            NA         44             54   49
#5            35         45             55   45
#6            36         46             56   46
#7            NA         47             57   52
#8            38         48             NA   43
#9            39         49             NA   44
#10           40         NA             60   50
```

Using base R, we can do similar thing by

```
continent_mean <- function(df, continent)  {
     df1 <- df[startsWith(names(df), "asia")]
     df1[continent] <- rowMeans(df1, na.rm = TRUE)
     df1
}
```

---

If we want `rowMeans` of all the continents together we can use `split.default`

```
sapply(split.default(df, sub("_.*", "", names(df))), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)

#      asia europe
# [1,]   46      1
# [2,]   47     17
# [3,]   38     13
# [4,]   49     14
# [5,]   45     20
# [6,]   46      6
# [7,]   52     17
# [8,]   43     23
# [9,]   44     19
#[10,]   50     20
```

Comment: Thanks for answering with multiple ways. However, I get a different output than yours for the first method you presented. I literally copied and pasted your code into my R session, but got something else. In fact, I got the same output as I presented in my post. Coded with dput() this is what I get: `structure(list(asia_bangkok = c(31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
NA, 38L, 39L, 40L), asia_tokyo = c(41L, 42L, 43L, NA, 45L, NA, 
NA, 48L, 49L, 50L), asia_kathmandu = c(NA, 52L, 53L, NA, NA, 
56L, 57L, NA, 59L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))`.  How come?

Comment: Strange. I tried the code on RStudio cloud, and got the same output as Ronak's. So the problem is on my local system somehow.

Comment: @Emman What `R.version` do you have on your local system and on cloud? Check package version as well for `dplyr` and `rlang`.

Comment: I found the problem. `mutate()` was masked by both `plyr` and `dplyr` libraries. Specifying  `dplyr::mutate(!!quo_name(continent) := rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE))` solved it, and I now get the same output as yours and RStudio-Cloud's on my local system too.