# Wide format: a function to calculate row means for specific batches of columns, then scale up for multiple batches

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, sapply

This is a followup question [to a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57542384/6105259) of mine about building a function for calculating row means.

I want to use any function of the `apply` family to iterate over my dataset and each time compute the row mean (which is what the function does) for a group of columns I specify. Unfortunately, I miss something critical in the way I should tweak `apply()`, because I get an error that I can't troubleshoot.

### Example Data

```r
capital_cities_df <-
 data.frame("europe_paris" = 1:10, 
           "europe_london" = 11:20, 
           "europe_rome" = 21:30,
           "asia_bangkok" = 31:40,
           "asia_tokyo" = 41:50,
           "asia_kathmandu" = 51:60)

set.seed(123)
capital_cities_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(capital_cities_df, 
function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA),
                         prob = c(0.70, 0.30),
                         size = length(cc), 
                         replace = TRUE) ]))

> capital_cities_df

   europe_paris europe_london europe_rome asia_bangkok asia_tokyo asia_kathmandu
1             1            NA          NA           NA         41             NA
2            NA            12          22           NA         42             52
3             3            NA          23           33         43             NA
4            NA            14          NA           NA         NA             NA
5            NA            15          25           35         45             NA
6             6            NA          NA           36         NA             56
7            NA            17          NA           NA         NA             57
8            NA            18          NA           38         48             NA
9            NA            19          NA           39         49             NA
10           10            NA          30           40         NA             60
```

### Custom Function

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

continent_mean <- function(df, continent)  {
  df %>%
    select(starts_with(continent)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(!!quo_name(continent) := rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE))
}

## works for a single case:
continent_mean(capital_cities_df, "europe")

   europe_paris europe_london europe_rome europe
1             1            NA          21     11
2             2            12          22     12
3             3            NA          23     13
4             4            14          NA      9
5            NA            15          25     20
6             6            16          26     16
7            NA            17          NA     17
8            NA            18          NA     18
9            NA            19          NA     19
10           10            20          30     20
```

### Trying to apply the function over the data, unsuccessfully

```r
apply(
  capital_cities_df,
  MARGIN = 2,
  FUN = continent_mean(capital_cities_df, continent = "europe")
)

Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'continent_mean(capital_cities_df, continent = "europe")' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Any other combination of the arguments in `apply()` didn't work either, nor did `sapply`. This unsuccessful attempt of using `apply` is only for one type of columns I wish to get the mean for ("europe"). However, my ultimate goal is to be able to pass `c("europe", "asia", etc.)` with `apply`, so I could get the custom function to create row means columns for all groups of columns I specify, in one hit.

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks!

### EDIT 19-AUG-2019

I was trying the solution suggested by A. Suliman (see below). It did work for the example data I posted here, but not when trying to scale it up to my real dataset, where I need to subset additional columns (rather than the "continent" batch only). More specifically, in my real data I have an ID column which I want to get outputted along the other data, when I apply my custom-made function.

### Example data including "ID" column

```r
capital_cities_df <- data.frame(
    "europe_paris" = 1:10,
    "europe_london" = 11:20,
    "europe_rome" = 21:30,
    "asia_bangkok" = 31:40,
    "asia_tokyo" = 41:50,
    "asia_kathmandu" = 51:60)
  
set.seed(123)
capital_cities_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA),
                                                 prob = c(0.70, 0.30),
                                                 size = length(cc), 
                                                 replace = TRUE) ]))

id <- 1:10
capital_cities_df <- cbind(id, capital_cities_df)

> capital_cities_df

   id europe_paris europe_london europe_rome asia_bangkok asia_tokyo asia_kathmandu
1   1            1            NA          NA           NA         41             NA
2   2           NA            12          22           NA         42             52
3   3            3            NA          23           33         43             NA
4   4           NA            14          NA           NA         NA             NA
5   5           NA            15          25           35         45             NA
6   6            6            NA          NA           36         NA             56
7   7           NA            17          NA           NA         NA             57
8   8           NA            18          NA           38         48             NA
9   9           NA            19          NA           39         49             NA
10 10           10            NA          30           40         NA             60
```

### My function (edited to select `id` as well)

```r
continent_mean <- function(df, continent)  {
  df %>%
    select(., id, starts_with(continent)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(!!quo_name(continent) := rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE))
}

> continent_mean(capital_cities_df, "europe") ## works in a single run

   id europe_paris europe_london europe_rome    europe
1   1            1            NA          NA  1.000000
2   2           NA            12          22 12.000000
3   3            3            NA          23  9.666667
4   4           NA            14          NA  9.000000
5   5           NA            15          25 15.000000
6   6            6            NA          NA  6.000000
7   7           NA            17          NA 12.000000
8   8           NA            18          NA 13.000000
9   9           NA            19          NA 14.000000
10 10           10            NA          30 16.666667
```

### Trying to apply the function beyond the single use (based on A. Suliman's method) -- unsuccessfully

```r
continents <- c("europe", "asia") 
lst <- lapply(continents, function(x) continent_mean(df=capital_cities_df[, grep(x, names(capital_cities_df))], continent=x))

## or:
purrr::map_dfc(continents, ~continent_mean(df=capital_cities_df[, grep(.x, names(capital_cities_df))], continent=.x))
```

In either case I get a variety of error messages:

> Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0
> and n

At other times:

> Error: invalid column index : NA for variable: 'NA' = 'NA'

All I wanted was a simple function to let me calculate row means per specification of which columns to run over, but this gets nasty for some reason. Even though I'm eager to figure out what's wrong with my code, if anybody has a better overarching solution for the entire process I'd be thankful too.

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with your code is the way you call `apply`. `FUN = function(x) yourfun(x, args)` would be the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply` to loop through `continents` then use `grep` to select columns with the current `continent`

```
continents <- c("europe", "asia") 
lst <- lapply(continents, function(x) continent_mean(df=capital_cities_df[, grep(x, names(capital_cities_df))], continent=x))
#To a dataframe not a list
do.call(cbind, lst)
```

Using `map_dfc` from `purrr` we can get the result in one step

```
purrr::map_dfc(continents, ~continent_mean(df=capital_cities_df[, grep(.x, names(capital_cities_df))], continent=.x))
```

## Update:

```
#grep will return column positions when they match with "europe" or "asia", e.g
> grep("europe", names(capital_cities_df))
[1] 2 3 4
#If we need the column names then we add value=TRUE to grep 
> grep("europe", names(capital_cities_df), value = TRUE)
[1] "europe_paris"  "europe_london" "europe_rome"
```

So to add a new column we can just use the `c()` function and call the function as usual

```
#NOTE: Here I'm using the old function without select
lst <- lapply(continents, function(x) continent_mean(df=capital_cities_df[, c('id',grep(x, names(capital_cities_df), value = TRUE))], continent=x))
do.call(cbind, lst)
id europe_paris europe_london europe_rome   europe id asia_bangkok asia_tokyo asia_kathmandu     asia
1   1            1            NA          NA  1.00000  1           NA         41             51 31.00000
2   2           NA            12          22 12.00000  2           NA         42             52 32.00000
3   3            3            13          23 10.50000  3           33         43             NA 26.33333
4   4           NA            14          NA  9.00000  4           NA         44             54 34.00000
5   5           NA            15          25 15.00000  5           35         45             55 35.00000
6   6            6            NA          NA  6.00000  6           36         46             56 36.00000
7   7            7            17          27 14.50000  7           NA         47             57 37.00000
8   8           NA            18          28 18.00000  8           38         48             NA 31.33333
9   9            9            19          29 16.50000  9           39         49             NA 32.33333
10 10           10            NA          30 16.66667 10           40         NA             60 36.66667

#We have one problem, id column gets duplicated, map_dfc with select will solve this issue
purrr::map_dfc(continents, ~continent_mean(df=capital_cities_df[, c('id',grep(.x, names(capital_cities_df), value = TRUE))], continent=.x)) %>%
#Don't select any column name ends with id followed by one digit
select(-matches('id\\d'))
```

If you'd like to use the new function with `select` then just pass `capital_cities_df` without `grep`, e.g using `map_dfc`

```
purrr::map_dfc(continents, ~continent_mean(df=capital_cities_df, continent=.x)) %>% 
select(-matches('id\\d'))
```

**Correction**: in *continent_mean*

```
continent_mean <- function(df, continent)  {
  df %>%
    select(., id, starts_with(continent)) %>%
    #Exclude id from the rowMeans calculation 
    dplyr::mutate(!!quo_name(continent) := rowMeans(.[grep(continent, names(.))], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works for the dataset I posted, but I'm unable to scale it up to my real data. As soon as I add another variable to my function's `select()`, applying it using your `apply`/`map_dfc` method -- it breaks. Just to make it clear, in my real data I also have an ID column (which is absent from this post's data example). Changing the function to `select(id, starts_with(continent))` throws an error with `apply`/`map_dfc`, but not when running the function with a single use (eg `continent_mean(capital_cities_df, "europe")`). Should I post a new question or edit the current post?

Comment: I went ahead and edited the post to reflect my problem.

Comment: @Emman please check my update. The problem was you did `df %>% select(., id, starts_with(continent))` in a df that doesn't contain a column called id, try this, `dftemp <- capital_cities_df[, grep("europe", names(capital_cities_df))];dftemp %>% select(., id, starts_with("europe"))`

Comment: This is perfect. I went ahead with your proposed new function and the shorter version of `map_dfc`, as it's more concise and uses variables rather than hard coding. I have a final question that has to do with "cosmetics": how to assign new names to the new mutated columns? In the line `dplyr::mutate(!!quo_name(continent) := rowMeans(.[grep(continent, names(.))], na.rm = TRUE))`, I want to name the new columns as _"asia_mean"_ or _"europe_mean"_. What is the appropriate way to do something like `paste0` over `!!quo_name(continent)` and `"_mean"`, within _this_ particular `mutate`? Thanks!

Comment: You're almost there, just change the _mutate_ into `dplyr::mutate(!!paste0(quo_name(continent),"_mean") := rowMeans(.[grep(continent, names(.))], na.rm = TRUE))`. This [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) tutorial will help you a lot.